# Is the data held within a ticket publicly visible in any way?

Tags: michelson, ticket, edo

I'm talking about the tickets feature introduced in Edo.

Is it safe to hold private data in a ticket basically - I'm talking about this in the context of a game where there is certain information that I do not want the particpants to be abe to see.

So is that data publically available on the chain?  Could someone write a ticket-reader wallet that just invokes READ_TICKET on the tickets in their wallet?  Things like that>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of tickets is completely transparent and can't be used in this way. In general, you cannot assume that on-chain data is unreadable by users. You can add encrypted data on chain, but to to decrypt it you will have to supply the key -- effectively making the data public.

You could use an off-chain oracle that feeds the hidden data to the contract. But the moment it is revealed by the oracle, it becomes public to the players.